# Update all model Express.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to update all my model using a put request on express.
For example I have a collection in mongoDB like this

```
{
    '_id': '123'
    'name' : 'jonh',
    'last' : 'smith',
    'email': 'js@dom.com',
    'phone': 'HTC',
    ...[more data]
}
```

Using a put request I send new data (not necessary all fields existing)
[image]
In my index.js I tried with:

```
router.put('/update/:id', function(req,res){
  Perfiles.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,req, function(err){
    if(err) { res.send(err);}
    res.json({messaje:'Done'});
  });
});
```

But my collection still without changes. I want to update even if the other fields are deleted

```
{
    '_id': '123'
    'name' : 'Carl',
    'phone': 'iPhone'
}
```

Comment: in your findByIdAndUpdate your giving req as your update query but params are in req.body

Comment: @Gatsbill Yep, I noticed that 5 minutes after post this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing req object as value to be updated.But what is req?

```
Perfiles.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,req, function(err){
    //what is req?
    console.log(req); 
    // it's a big express' object
})
```

you need to provide what key and value to update, based on whether you send the value from url's parameter or url's query or if you POST an object then req.body

```
router.put('/update/:id', function(req,res){
  //since you POST the object then use req.body
  var newObject = { 
         name: req.body.name, 
         phone: req.body.phone
      }; 

  Perfiles.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, newObject, function(err){
    if(err) { res.send(err);}
    res.json({messaje:'Done'});
  });
});
```